# The code on the python does not work correctly when int(input()) is used

Tags: python-3.x

This code should output the penultimate number from the array!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    A = [n]
    for array in A:
        array = list(set(array))
        high = len(array)-1
        item = (high-1)
        if array != 0:
            a = sorted(array)
            print(a[item:high])
```

Comment: As always, I suggest executing the script on [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) to see where you expected a different behaviour.

Comment: The code as shown results in printing -57, which is the second largest number and thus the penultimate in your example.  Why do you not think it works?

Comment: May be you need to edit your title, as there is no `int(input())` in your code.

Comment: for your question here, `a[item:high]` give you slice of the list, just use `a[item]` to get the number. For list size >= 2, you can simply use `a[-2]`.

Comment: it only works correctly with pre-written numbers.  it refuses to work with input.  + to everything I need it to print numbers without brackets and that they be of integer type!  i tried (.join) doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `57 57 -57 57` before your edit is what you will input, `input()` return this input as string `'57 57 -57 57'` which can't convert to integer. So you need to split the string first, you can do the split and conversion of integer at the same time by list comprehension:

```
# a = [57, 57, -57, 57]
a = [int(n) for n in input().split()]
```

You can now get the penultimate number by:

```
print(a[-2]) # Output: -57
```

`set()` and `sorted()` will remove duplicates and change the order of your input, you can still do that if this is what you want:

```
# sorted(set(a)) = [-57, 57]
print(sorted(set(a))[-2]) # Output: -57
```

IndexError will be raised if you input nothing or only one number.